# Difference between "vorkommen"," passieren", "sich ereignen", "geschehen", "stattfinden", "vorfallen"?

Tags: meaning, difference

What are the differences between the verbs `vorkommen`, `passieren`, `sich ereignen`, `geschehen`, `stattfinden`, `vorfallen`?

Could someone explain the difference(s) to me, please.

Comment: What are the results of your dictionary research?

Comment: to happen and to occur ! :/

Comment: @Stephie, Let's not be so tough. It can be confusing to have so many alternatives.

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe not tough, just trying to understand what OP already knows/understood. (What you can't see is that there are no close votes yet.) And there are a few rules on the site after all.

Comment: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/628/how-do-i-ask-good-on-topic-questions-for-translations-or-about-differences

Comment: Related: http://german.stackexchange.com/q/29783/1224 # http://german.stackexchange.com/q/7430/1224

Comment: But "to happen" and "to occur" can't be the only possible translations? (If they are, throw out your dictionary.)

Comment: @Robert                                                                                                      to occur 
to happen
to transpire
to be effected
to appear
to exist
to seem
to be found
to pass
to negotiate.....

Comment: Aus 6 Begriffen lassen sich 15 paarweise Vergleiche bilden. Bevorzugst Du sie in einer bestimmten Reihenfolge?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Passieren** is informal (it's also what children would be using), **vorkommen** still a bit informal. **Geschehen** and **vorfallen** feels neutral to me, **sich ereignen** and **stattfinden** more formal. **Sich ereignen** might sound old-fashioned.

**Vorfallen** is almost always used for serious negative events, **passieren** for less serious but still negative events, and **vorkommen** will sometimes refer to negative events as well. **Sich ereignen** and **geschehen** feel neutral, **stattfinden** a bit positive.

**Stattfinden** is for something which is planned and which will take some time, e.g. describing some festival. **Passieren** and **geschehen** imply a rather short timeframe, almost a point in time, and a random element.

**Vorkommen** describes something rather rare, **passieren** perhaps a bit more frequent but still exceptional. **Geschehen** and **sich ereignen** do not imply any frequence one way or another. **Stattfinden** suggests that it *might* be something recurring. **Vorfallen** is probably referring to something that is occurring more often than it should, no matter how often that is.

Some examples:

- Es kann **vorkommen**, dass die Hose beim Waschen ausfärbt.
  Das kann doch mal **vorkommen**, ist nicht so schlimm.
- Und dabei ist es **passiert**. Einfach so, ich kann nichts dafür.
  Was ist denn hier **passiert**?
  Das kann jedem mal **passieren**.
- Und es **ereignete sich** in der Weihnachtsnacht, dass im Stall zu Bethlehem…
- Das **geschieht** ihm ganz recht! (Schadenfreude)
- Bei Regen **findet** die Feier im Haus **statt**.
- Da ist bestimmt mal was **vorgefallen**, dass das Kind jetzt so Angst vor lauten Stimmen hat.

Note that this answer concentrates on the almost common meaning between these words. Some of them have different meanings as well, for which none of the others would be synonymous, like “eine Grenze **passieren**”, “das Öl-**Vorkommen** begutachten”, “das **Geschehen** aus der Luft betrachten”, …

Comment: Nice explanation. It's really difficult to distinguish them. But I think _passieren_ very well has a negative connotation. To add some confusion: _"Es muss etwas geschehen, aber es darf nichts passieren!"_. I'd translate that with _"Something must happen (or change) but nothing bad must happen!"_ because _passieren_ implies that sth. bad happens or has happened.

Comment: @PerlDog: I tend to agree, although there are counterexamples. *“Was passiert denn in dem Film?”* and *“in diesem Kaff passiert ja eh nie etwas”* seem to imply a positive connotation for *passieren*, but perhaps that's a matter of perspective: to the bored observer even (slightly) bad events seem preferable to no events at all, in both cases. I'll edit to shift the word a bit more towards negative.

Comment: Well, I also tried to answer the OP's question but found examples and counterexamples for every single verb. So I abandoned and appreciated your answer. As said, the difference is so tiny and hard to explain. To me the only undoubted translation is "stattfinden" and "take place".

Comment: @PerlDog: Feel free to edit in some of these examples you came up with, if you feel they help illustrating the range of typical use cases.

Comment: Nice explanation, I would probably refer to the nouns, too.

Comment: Diese Fragen laden immer zu ad-hoc Verallgemeinerungen ein, die einem kritischen Blick dann nicht stich halten. Wie @MvG schon schrieb - such mal nach Gegenbeispielen und streich mutig weg; dann bleibt nicht viel.